# Sorting timestamp into intervals PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, datetime

I want to take a set of timestamps (from mySQL DATE_TIME) and return the amount of occurrences in each hour for the last say, 24 hours. Basically I'm trying to make a real-time graph which would show the amount of recent database activity.

An example result might be..

```
//4 occurrences between now and one hour ago
$hour1=4;
//2 occurrences between 2 and 3 hours ago
$hour2=2;
//7 occurrences between 3 and 4 hours ago
$hour3=7;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT ..., count(*) AS occurences, hour(timestampfield) AS hour
FROM ...
WHERE timestampfield >= (now() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
GROUP BY hour(timestampfield)
```

get the count of all occcurences in the past 24 hours, grouped by the hour they occured in.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you add one field to MySQL table where you store DATE_TIME hour value and count() occurrencies grouping by that field?